# How to save element's status in array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

Could someone help me with the below problem?

I have an array of objects. I am setting the elements to "true" with a button (next one each time on click).
I would like to store these "true" value changes in the array, so when I open up the app again, the one that was set true would be true by default.

```
  public x : any = ["x0", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6",
  "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12"];

//to turn an element true
 buttonclick(){
    this.counter+=1;
    this.storage.set("Count",this.counter);
    var xNum=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("x"+this.counter));
    this.x[xNum] = true;
//unfortunately, it does not save the true status of the elements:
    this.storage.set('xArray', JSON.stringify(this.x));
}
```

Comment: are you using local localstorage

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("x" + this.counter))` is exactly the same as `"x" + this.counter`

Comment: As brk suggest, you should use the localStorage API to store the status. Check for the MDN documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers.
If I add:
localStorage.setItem("TestXArray", this.x);
How can I retrieve the array's "true X values e.g. in the constructor, to boot up the req. values as true?